# Why cant center the divs within a flexbox model

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am not able to align center the following divs on the full page width:

- header
- content
- footer

But it does not work! Whats needs to be changed within my CSS to get it working?

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#header {
  height: 50px;
}

#hero-wrapper { 
  background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/1500?random');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  color:#ffffff;
}

#hero {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
  #hero-text{
    font-family:'Roboto';
    font-weight:900;
    font-size:2em;
    text-align:center;
  }

#hero-footnote {
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
}

#content {
  width: 1024px;
  background-color:green;
}

#footer {
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  weight: 400;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* position: fixed; */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.685em;
  color: #1a1717;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#footer-info {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 42px;
}

span#footer-social-icons {

}
span#copyright-info {
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  weight: 400;
  padding-left:10px;
}

span#contact-link {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  weight: 200;
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cabin&family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@200&family=Roboto:wght@400;500;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="wrapper">
  
   <div id="header">header</div>
  
   <div id="hero-wrapper">
      <div id="hero">
         <div id="hero-text">
            <span id="hero-header">sell the product</span><br />
            <span id="hero-sub">On this page for less</span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="hero-footnote">&copy; Copyright Text</div>
   </div>
  
   <div id="content">
      <!-- Content-Loop -->
      <div class="article">
         Here come the Article
      </div>
   </div>
  
   <div id="footer">
      <div id="footer-info">
         <span id="footer-social-icons">&#xf102;</span>&nbsp;<span id="copyright-info">Made with love by Y.</span>&nbsp;<span id="contact-link">Contact</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `align-items: center;` to `#wrapper`.

Normally if you would have `flex-direction: row;` centering things would be `justify-content: center;` but as column change the axis so does the alignment properties. They kinda "go with the axis".

One thing though, I would strongly suggest that you don't style with id, use classes for that.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#header {
  height: 50px;
}

#hero-wrapper { 
  background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/1500?random');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  color:#ffffff;
}

#hero {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
  #hero-text{
    font-family:'Roboto';
    font-weight:900;
    font-size:2em;
    text-align:center;
  }

#hero-footnote {
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
}

#content {
  width: 1024px;
  background-color:green;
}

#footer {
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  weight: 400;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* position: fixed; */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.685em;
  color: #1a1717;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#footer-info {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 42px;
}

span#footer-social-icons {

}
span#copyright-info {
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  weight: 400;
  padding-left:10px;
}

span#contact-link {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  weight: 200;
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cabin&family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@200&family=Roboto:wght@400;500;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="wrapper">
  
   <div id="header">header</div>
  
   <div id="hero-wrapper">
      <div id="hero">
         <div id="hero-text">
            <span id="hero-header">sell the product</span><br />
            <span id="hero-sub">On this page for less</span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="hero-footnote">&copy; Copyright Text</div>
   </div>
  
   <div id="content">
      <!-- Content-Loop -->
      <div class="article">
         Here come the Article
      </div>
   </div>
  
   <div id="footer">
      <div id="footer-info">
         <span id="footer-social-icons">&#xf102;</span>&nbsp;<span id="copyright-info">Made with love by Y.</span>&nbsp;<span id="contact-link">Contact</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to center the text, use text-align: center and the parts?

Or if you are looking to do more centered-content, maybe make your #header, #content, and #footer the following:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
```

Basically, flex boxes within flex boxes.